# Assign a REST method response to a value

Tags: rest, get, return-value, powershell-4.0

I have a powershell script and I am trying to assign the response of the GET method to value `$a`. Bellow I have my code but it does not work. How can I assign the response to this value?

Thank you

```
$a = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://cloud.skytap.com/templates/555949" -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers | out-null
Write-Host "$a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending your code to out-null, which removes the output!

Remove `| Out-Null` and you'll find that your assignment to $a is working.  Or perhaps you'll find an error message instead.  If so, let me know and I'll do my best to help you.

To clarify, you should be running this instead.

```
$a = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://cloud.skytap.com/templates/555949" -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
```